# Postgresql: Making timeseries table smaller

Tags: postgresql, size, row, storage

I am using PostgreSQL 12.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit and I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.historian_new_data_id_v2 (
    "timestamp" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    value float8 NOT NULL,
    quality float4 NOT NULL,
    tagname_id int2 NOT NULL
);
```

I would expect this table to take 8 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 22 bytes per row, as I think there are no alignment issues. Even in the worst case, with all fields 8-bytes-aligned I would expect it to take 8 * 4 = 32 bytes per row.

However, these are the size stats I get for the table:

```
with row_count as (select COUNT(*) as c from historian_new_data_id_v2)
select
    c as "number of rows",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('historian_new_data_id_v2')) as "total table size",
    pg_total_relation_size('historian_new_data_id_v2')::numeric / c as " bytes/row"
from row_count
```

**number of rows**: 409858537

**table size**: 20 GB

**bytes / row**: 52.1783453494345538

That is a lot of overhead! 52 bytes per row instead of the expected 22 or worse case 32. How is this difference explained?

And also, any advice to make this table smaller (the amount of rows is going to skyrocket soon)?

Answer (score 1):

Each row in PostgreSQL has system columns:

```
select attname, attnum, attlen
  from pg_attribute
 where attrelid = 'public.historian_new_data_id_v2'::regclass
 order by attnum;

+------------+----------+----------+
| attname    | attnum   | attlen   |
|------------+----------+----------|
| tableoid   | -6       | 4        |
| cmax       | -5       | 4        |
| xmax       | -4       | 4        |
| cmin       | -3       | 4        |
| xmin       | -2       | 4        |
| ctid       | -1       | 6        |
| timestamp  | 1        | 8        |
| value      | 2        | 8        |
| quality    | 3        | 4        |
| tagname_id | 4        | 2        |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

This columns available to select, if you want:

```
select tableoid, cmax, xmax, cmin, xmin, ctid, timestamp, value, quality, tagname_id
  from public.historian_new_data_id_v2;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of (some of) these fields to optimize for size?

Comment: This is not directly connected to the question. Still, you could have a look at https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression. I am not working for the company or promoting the product. I am trying it and thought you may find it interesting. It is an extension and turned out to be incredibly easy to set up.